# How to substract a range within a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have cells with a '-' and numbers within the same cell. I want to apply a formulae =A1-10 and apply it to the enter column. What do I do to subtract 10 across all the cells in the column

```
3955 - 3948     ---- o/p 3945 - 3938
3936            ---- o/p 3926
3920
3900 - 3890
3860
3831
3821
3800 - 3805
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=map(A:A,lambda(z,if(z="",,join(" - ",index(split(z,"-")-10)))))
```

[image]